# These lines should change all objects in the list into integers, but they're still showing up as strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a list, playerlocation, which I am using as coordinates. The coordinates are entered with an input() command, so they appear as strings rather than integers. I thought this block of code would solve it,

```py
playerlocation =(input("Player location?"))
playerlocation = list(playerlocation.split(","))

for x in playerlocation:
try:     
     x = int(x)
     coordsareintegers = True
     print(playerlocation)
except:
     coordsareintegers = False
```

but `print(playerlocation)` is returning something like ['1','1'], meaning they're still strings.

I've tried using an `int()` command wherever the coordinates are used, but that's really tedious.

Comment: `int(input())`?

Comment: I should have included the two lines above
        playerlocation =(input("Player location?"))
        playerlocation = list(playerlocation.split(","))

the items are being entered as an x,y coordinate, then the string is split

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` on your input. Something like:

```
>>> coords = '1,2'
>>> split = coords.split(',')
>>> split
['1', '2']
>>> ints = map(int, split)
>>> ints
<map object at 0x0000000002476978>
>>> list(ints)
[1, 2]
```

Apply accordingly to your code.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a while loop with try except to keep asking the user to input the right `player location format`, and it will quit the loop and print player location in case entries are valid integers comma separated:

```
while True:
    try:
        x, y = input("Player location: ").split(',')
        player_location = [int(x), int(y)]
        print('player location:', player_location)
        break
    except:
        print('error: you should enter an integers x,y for player location, try again!\n')
```

example output:

```
Player location: blah..blah
error: you should enter an integers x,y for player location, try again!

Player location: 3,4
player location: [3, 4]
```